# How to find existing instances "instance root" (MS SQL)?

Tags: sql-server, instance, setup

I'm installing a new instance of MS SQL. There is a step asking to specify instance root. The current DBA is off but I want to follow his logic / way of doing things.
The installer lists the existing instances but does not specify the configured paths. A quick google search doesn't reveal anything useful either.
The question is in the title.

Comment: check this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms143547.aspx) and [other one](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa176606(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: nothing in either of them about "instance root"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it by comparing several articles and looking at existing file structure and registry under:   `HKLM\software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.INSTANCEID\Setup`
There are a few "path" and "dir" references, most of them quite long. The common denominator seems to be the `SqlProgramDir` key, for all the existing instances. In our case the DBA decided to put them all under "D:\SQL\Data\"